# What is the best way to control thread creation in Java on a given machine?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, operating-system, threadpool

In my application, I want to create threads based on the user's input.
For e.g., if user provides 10, I simply create a pool of 10 threads to perform some operation. There is no control on the user's input. I don't want to create 10k threads if the user provides 10k as an input. It will be overkill for the machine. Any recommendations?

How can I control thread pool count?
How can I calculate the max #of threads I can create on a given machine?

Comment: *There's no control on user's input...*: well, you have (and want) control. So, `createThreads(Math.min(userInputNumber, maximumAllowedBySystemConfig))`. And keep track of how many you've created if the user can repeat the request.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Any recommendations?***

This cannot be easily achieved without making some profiling to the application in the production environment and getting some real stats that help you identify the optimal conditions in which the maximum usage of CPU is achieved (See [Amdahl’s law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)).

That said, one thing is for sure, and you already know it: you should not create more threads than the number which would be optimal for your running environment.

Making a summary from [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://jcip.net/):

Item 8.2 Sizing thread pools

> The ideal size for a thread pool depends on the types of tasks that
>   will be submitted and the characteristics of the deployment system.
>   Thread pool sizes should rarely be hard-coded; instead pool sizes
>   should be provided by a configuration mechanism or computed
>   dynamically by consulting `Runtime.availableProcessors`.

For example,

> for compute-intensive tasks, an N<sub>*cpu*</sub>-processor system usually
>   achieves optimum utilization with a thread pool of N<sub>*cpu*</sub> +
>   1 threads.

and given

> N<sub>cpu</sub> = number of CPUs
>
> U<sub>cpu</sub> = target CPU utilization, 0 ≤ U cpu ≤ 1
>
> W/C = ratio of wait time to compute time
>
> The optimal pool size for keeping the processors at the desired
>   utilization is:

(and this should answer ***How can I calculate max #of threads I can create on a given machine?***)

> N<sub>threads</sub> = N<sub>cpu</sub> ∗ U<sub>cpu</sub> ∗ (1 + W/C)

You can determine the number of available CPUs using

```
int numberOfCPU = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

> ***How can I control thread pool count ?***

You could (and should) use any of the [concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) classes added to Java instead of creating and managing `Thread`s by yourself. For example [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).